# can we auto swap the images in lwuit

Tags: java, lwuit

I mean as a slider, like so:

```
Image img[]=new Image{"a.png","b.png","c.png"};

for(int i=0;i<img.length;i++){
  limg = (new CustomLabel(img[i]));
  cnti.addComponent(limg);
  addComponent(cnti);
}
```

Sorry, I hope you all getting my question.

Comment: You will need to elaborate more your questions. Tell us what you wanna do, what are you trying and some of your code to take a look on it and try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a `Label` then replace it using `Container.replace()` while using a slide transition.

If you want to allow the user to swipe then you can theoretically you can use a a horizontal list but there were some bugs there in LWUIT.

There are more powerful options in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com) including `ImageView`.